# Anemometer with Raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

What I really need help with is a way in which I should calculate wind speed via an anemometer  with Python. The only problem I have so far is measuring how many "clicks" a second happen.  One revolution of the anemometer causes a switch to open and close 2 times.

An example of what I wish the code to do would be the following:

10 clicks per second = 5 miles per hour wind

Any help would be much appreciated on how I would measure pulses per second.

Regards.

Code so far (this continuously prints an output and notes if the switch is pressed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import uadi2c
import mcp23017

addr2 = 0x21
dio = uadi2c.uadi2c(addr2, debug=False)
portA = mcp23017.GPIOA
portB = mcp23017.GPIOB
dirA = mcp23017.IODIRA
dirB = mcp23017.IODIRB
# chip 1, all output, chip 2 A input, B output
dio.write8(dirA, 0)
dio.write8(dirB, 0x40)


# Now loop reading PA and writing to PB and the terminal

while True:
    stuff = dio.readU8(portB)
    dio.write8(portA, stuff)
    print 'Data read from port B: {0:=08b}'.format(stuff)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you post some code that doesn't work, most people here will be happy to help. Otherwise, you may find it tough to get an answer...

Comment: http://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi/